# How to bind volumes that were sshfs'd with the right permissions?

Tags: docker, sshfs

I use my laptop to connect to a remote Ubunto (18.04) machine (let's call it `A`).
I sshfs'd a directory from another machine (=`B`) to `A`.
Now, I try to run a docker container on `A`, and bind the volume that I sshfs'd.
When I try to perform some operation on that volume, I get permissions denied.

To trace the problem, I created the following script.

```
BIN_VERSION="1.0.0"
DIR=<**ENTER HERE**>
seq 10 > ${DIR}/a
chmod 400 ${DIR}/a

sudo docker run \
  -v /${DIR}/:/tmp/ \
  gcr.io/deepvariant-docker/deepvariant:"${BIN_VERSION}" \
  cat /tmp/a

rm ${DIR}/a
```

The script basically creates a file, changes the permissions of that file to be minimal (read only for the user), and then binds it's volume to the docker. Then the docker tries to read it. This is a good simulator for my problem.

To isolate variables, I ran the scipt with different `DIR` values.
For the following values of DIR, the script ran fine: `["/tmp", "/home", "/groups", "groups/nshomron"]. For` DIR=/groups/nshomron/yonathans2`, the script fails with the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/groups/nshomron/yonathans2': mkdir /groups/nshomron/yonathans2: file exists.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Relevant information:

- When I run `ls -l /groups/`:

  ```
    total 4
    drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Oct  4 12:52 nshomron
  ```
- When I run `ls -l /groups/nshomron/`:

  ls: cannot access '/groups/nshomron/tomr': Transport endpoint is not connected

  total 4

  d????????? ? ?     ?       ?            ? tomr

  drwxrwxr-x 1 93501 1499 4096 Oct  4 13:05 yonathans2

The directory to which I sshfs'd is /groups/yonathans2. I think that the owner and user id are ones from the other filesystem I sshfs'd from.

Does anyone know how to perform such volume binding?